# How to create a Frame to an external webpage in a Silverlight XAML page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, frame

I'm pretty new to .NET, trying to do a simple XAML webpage with a 200x200 frame with Google inside it. I have a XAML page which looks like this:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Oleo.CI.Content.IU.Form.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"
    xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input"
    xmlns:telerikNavigation="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
    xmlns:telerikGrid="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
    xmlns:uiControl="clr-namespace:Oleo.CI.Contenidos.IU.Control;assembly=Oleo.CI.Contenidos.IU.Control"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="1002" Width="1002" Height="812" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 10 18 -10">
          <navigation:Frame x:Name="Cont" Source="http://www.google.com" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Height="200"/>
          <TextBlock Text="Oferta" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </StackPanel>
 </UserControl>
```

I have tried with both navigation:Frame and sdk:Frame yet the frame is not getting displayed on the page with that code (other controls like RadGrids of TextBlocks work perfectly). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone shed some light over me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot open web page inside Silverlight frame. Frame class represents a control that supports navigation to and from **Silverlight pages**. 
You can see that navigation is failed by handling NavigationFailed event of Frame.

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="Cont" Source="http://www.google.com" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Height="200"
            NavigationFailed="Cont_NavigationFailed"/>
```

It will throw exception with the message:
**Content for the URI cannot be loaded. The URI may be invalid.**

**Update**:
You can achieve your goal using iframe tag from Html.

This is how you going to do:
While creating Silverlight Application, Visual Studio creates two project in your solution. One for Silverlight application, which produces .xap file and a simple Asp.Net Web site which includes TestPage.aspx by default. Your .xap file is included in this web page and height and width of your .xap is set to 100%. Of course you can chnage it as you want. Currently I have set it to 50% for both Height and Width. If you gonna right click your mouse on this part in browser you will see Silverlight Context Menu. BUt in other parts of you web application you will see default context Menu for Html Web page. 
So you must add iframe tag to that page.

```
    <iframe src="http://www.msdn.com" height="700px" width="700px"></iframe>
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            width="50%" height="50%">
            <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap" />
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="background" value="white" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                    style="border-style: none" />
            </a>
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
            border: 0px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

But, I must say that you can't open google web sites in iframe. Because google is blocking iframe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then how could I achieve my objective in Silverlight and render Google on a Frame?